# Unable to update item in Firebase using Angular5

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using angular version: **5.2.0**, angularfire2: **5.0.0-rc.7** and firebase version: **4.13.1**. 
I have a scenario in which I'm adding products to cart. If the same item is already present in the cart then the quantity will be increased the one. In my case, it is adding new item every time instead of updating the existing one.

Below is my service class. I tried to print item inside **addToCart** method but it is coming as **null**. Even after going through many searches, I'm not able find out the solution. Please guide or correct me.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Product } from './models/product';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class ShoppingCartService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  private create() {
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }

  private getCart(cartId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId);
  }

  private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
  }

  private async getOrCreateCartId() {
    const cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (!cartId) { return cartId; }
    const result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;
  }

  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    const cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    console.log(product.key);
    const itemRef = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
    const item$: Observable<any> = itemRef.snapshotChanges();

    item$.take(1).subscribe(item => {
      console.log(item.key);
      itemRef.update({
        product: product,
        quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 1
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed this boolean.. 
`if (!cartId) { return cartId; }`, take away `!`..
should be `if (cartId) { return cartId; }`

Comment: @JoshuaChan. yes that was one mistake. but still I'm getting item.quantity = undefined.